# optimization issue with splitting an image into channels

Tags: c++, image-processing, optimization

[image]

here is my code, my "algorithm" is trying to take a bayer image, or an RGB image, and separate the channel G, which is the Luma (or even grayscale) into the different channels of the color,

an example Bayer Pattern

[image]

```
void Utilities::SeparateChannels(int* channelR, int* channelG, int* channelB, double*& gr, double*& r, double*& b, double*& gb,int _width, int _height, int _colorOrder)
{
    //swith case the color Order
    int counter_R = 0;
    int counter_GR = 0;
    int counter_GB = 0;
    int counter_B = 0;

    switch (_colorOrder)
    {

        //grbg
    case 0: 
        for (int j = 0; j < _width; j++)
        {           
            for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)
                {                    
                    gr[counter_GR] = channelG[i*_width+ j];
                    counter_GR++;
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    r[counter_R] = channelG[i*_width+ j];
                    counter_R++;
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    b[counter_B] =channelG[i*_width+ j];
                    counter_B++;
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    gb[counter_GB] = channelG[i*_width+ j];
                    counter_GB++;
                }
            }
        }
```

I ran the profiler on 70 images, I attached my results.
Can you suggest a way to optimize my code?

Comment: Just for curiosity, what profiler did you use?

Comment: Can you explain the code? What do you mean separate channels here? You're apparently only "reading" the green channel, and splitting that into some unexplained 4 pieces of output. And what's the purpose of the type conversion (int -> double)?

Comment: @Amit i separate one channel of data into a few channels

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. Please update your post with details of the input & required output of the algorithm. It's not clear what the algorithm actually does. The types are unclear, the variable names don't make much sense (I'm assuming you're dealing with RGB pixels as the title suggests)... It's impossible to "optimize" an algorithm without understanding it.

Comment: You still didn't answer why you're type converting. That's definitely a heavy cost operation. Also, are you only using channelG? why are the other channels passed in then?

Comment: @Amit the other channels are used later on, please do not be concerned about them. which type conversion Am I doing ?

Comment: You're converting `int`s to `double`s. That's VERY expensive compared to anything else you're doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the loops, first iterate over the height. Then you can calculate i * _width before the second loop and calculate this 1 time instead of _width times.

Comment: Simply swapping the order of loops will result in a different ouput, unless the counters are also modified which will probably result in the same complexity.

Comment: @Amit I think that the goal of swapping the loops is not to reduce complexity but to make the code more cache-friendly.

Comment: @PaoloM how will that change make it more cache-friendly? you're swapping a mutiplication and random access in one place with multiplication and random access in another place. It's the same.

Comment: @Amit Right now your memory accesses are all over the place, so you get nearly zero cache usage. If you swap the loops you will access nearby bytes so the cache reduces memory latency. I wouldn't be surprised to see a factor 20 speed-up in this szenario.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck - First I didn't ask the question, I just questioned the answer :-). Second, my point was that this method replaces random reads with random writes, where the other side is serial in both cases (random read -> serial write vs. serial read -> random write). I guess it's still in improvement though.

Answer (score 1):

You test `i%2==0` in the first `if`, then you test it again in the second `if`, then you test if `i%2==1` in the third `if` and yet again in the fourth. If  you nested your if statements then you wouldn't have to keep testing, and if you know `i%2 != 0` you can deduce it must be 1, likewise with j.

```
if(i%2==0){
   if(j%2==0){
   }else{
      // j%2 is pretty likely to be 1
   }
}else{
     // i%2 is pretty likely to be 1
}
```

In fact, you can go further than that... if j is your row counter, it will not vary all the way across any row, so you could do one test at the start of each row and then execute a different loop according to whether you are on an odd or an even row without testing the row index for every pixel.

Answer (score 1):

The whole algorithm can be reduced to an inner loop that de-interleaves a section of the input array into 2 seperate output arrays. The 2 output arrays are changing for each row, and their selection depends on the input type (`_colorOrder`).

So.. first change your algorithm to work like this:

```
void Utilities::SeparateChannels(int* channelR, int* channelG, int* channelB, double*& gr, double*& r, double*& b, double*& gb,int _width, int _height, int _colorOrder)
{
    //swith case the color Order
    int counter_R = 0;
    int counter_GR = 0;
    int counter_GB = 0;
    int counter_B = 0;
    double *split1, *split2;

    switch (_colorOrder)
    {

        //grbg
    case 0: 
         for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
         {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                split1 = gr + counter_GR;
                split2 = r + counter_R;
                counter_GR += _width / 2;
                counter_R += _width / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                split1 = b + counter_B;
                split2 = gb + counter_GB;
                counter_B += _width / 2;
                counter_GB += _width / 2;
            }

            int *channel = channelG + (i * _width);

         // deinterleave(channel, split1, split2, _width);
         }
```

Now all you need to do is de-interleave `channel` into `split1` & `split2` over `_width` elements. Do that in an optimized (ASM?), inlined function.

Comment: Can you explain what does deinterleave means? and I don't want to go to assembly code. this is not a real time application.

Comment: There are (generally) 2 types of algorithm optimizations: 1. reduce time complexity (that requires optimizing the "logic" behind the algorithm) 2. optimize the inner loop. Since 1 is not possible in this case, you're left with 2, and that requires being as fast as possible in the inner loop, and that might be best if done using ASM in this case (it's a simple, logic-free inner loop).

Comment: Deinterleave would be the opposite of interleave, which is the process of combining multiple inputs into a single output where items in the output  are "picked" one at a time from each input (and you can always look things like this using that internet thing).

Comment: Lastly, if this is not a real time application, and I guess what you really mean is that you don't really want to optimize it (real-time is not the only scenario where you want effecient code), why did you ask the question in the first place?

Comment: because I want to have better performance, but do not want to use ASM for that.